# How to use batch files C#

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file

I have a file named ["text.bat"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBCcq.png) (example), if you execute the files it asks for a prompt "test", then it outputs "testtest"

How do i monitor the output from the batch file, and also doing input.

Comment: Look at `ProcessStartInfo` class from `System.Diagnostics` namespace, and its `RedirectStandardInput/Output/Error` properties. There are too many posts at SO and Microsoft docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo?view=net-7.0#properties

Comment: Duplicate of many posts.

Comment: Why do you need a batch file anyway, why not just execute whatever it is directly from C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to redirect process's input and output:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ProcessStandardInputSample
{
    class StandardInputTest
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            using (Process myProcess = new Process())
            {
                myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "text.bat";
                myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                myProcess.Start();
                StreamWriter myStreamWriter = myProcess.StandardInput;
                myStreamWriter.WriteLine("test");
                Console.WriteLine(myProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
                myProcess.WaitForExit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can find good explanation in [ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput?view=net-7.0) and [ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput?view=net-7.0).

Comment: Why you remove comments/explanations from code (they was before last edits)? Now it's same as @this_isName answer: just pure code and "you should do that" :) Get back comments with "**why** OP should do that" and "**what** that code does".

Comment: @Auditive I added link to product documentation. I guess I'm not able to explain the matter better.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
    ProcessStartInfo processInfo;
Process process;

processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("path to batch" );
processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

process = Process.Start(processInfo);
string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(output);
process.WaitForExit();

process.Close();
```

Comment: Please don't post pure code with "Take that" comment. Try provide a little explanation, why OP should use your example, what it does, how your code works etc. Clarifying explanation leads to less additional questions